# Why aren't people going to The Moon any more?

Tags: the-moon, moonlanding

In 1969 America landed on the moon, and at that time our technology was not as good as it is now. So my question is, we have much more advanced technology than in 1969, so why are we not utilising this technology and why are the USA and/or Russia not going to the Moon any more? With our current technology we should able go to The Moon daily...

Comment: This post is off topic and should probably moved to http://space.stackexchange.com/,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see from your comment on another post that you are a so-called skeptic, so no answer that is given will satisfy your irrational beliefs.

The simple reason is that it is very expensive; nothing to do with technological capabilities. And as there is little to be gained scientifically, then astronomers/geologists etc. would rather spend the money elsewhere.

Politicians are unwilling to ask taxpayers/voters to finance further manned (or womanned) trips to the Moon. For instance each space shuttle mission cost around a billion dollars. The cost of the Apollo programme in today's money would easily exceed 100 billion dollars.

Priorities may change when a Chinese person walks on the Moon...

Also worth noting that neither the USA or Russia have the launch capabilities of a Saturn V or similar at the moment. https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/5459/russian-manned-moon-landing-capability-today

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48124/discussion-on-answer-by-rob-jeffries-why-arent-people-going-to-the-moon-any-mor).